# Using Google Business Email simultaneously with other mail server for one domain

Tags: email, email-server

My partner is having some problems with delivering and receiving emails. They asked me to check Google Business Email, if it can provide a solution.
My question is: Is it possible to split users into two groups? One group of users using Google Business Email, the other one using the former mail server. Asking this, because there are around 40 employees there and the price for 40 accounts at Google might be a bit high for my partner.

With an example (3 users):

user1@partner.co.uk
user2@partner.co.uk
user3@partner.co.uk

Lets say i only want to set up Google Business Email for user1 and leave the other two users (user2 and user3) using the mail server already installed. Is this possible?
If i change the MX records for the domain to point at Google mailservers, then user2 and user3 will have problems sending/receiving emails, right? (Even if i leave the old MX records considering Google servers got highest priority.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about is referred to as SMTP namespace sharing.  If the mail systems support it and you know how to configure it, yes.  Otherwise, you'd have to do some tricky mail forwarding to a fake domain and then change outbound addresses to the right SMTP domain which gets complex and frustrating.

Comment: An example to support the argument. `postfix` is pretty flexible and you can compose a flat db to re-write recipient addresses (presumably the 1/2 you want to go to Google). But it becomes a maintenance nightmare. See: http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html